# Spectrum Of Metals

Tags: physical-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

Recently, I've read that when metals are exposed to a high voltage source, metals produce a spectrum. I am curious on what is the minimum value of that 'high voltage'? Is the spectrum due to the high voltage depends on the atomic properties of the metal? Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Do a search for DC arc spectroscopy or arc spectroscopy or similar terms. There is a vast amount of published research in the area!

Comment: Your question will probably be closed, I think it is too broad and contains parts that could be on-topic in Physics SE but not here. A very important aspect is the atmosphere where the electrical discharge is happening. Air molecules slow the electrons considerably, so even if you have 1,000 volts in your discharge, the average kinetic energy of the electrons could be tens of volts or less, so you need to consider the power (voltage and current) and how it is heating the metal and removing atoms and their chemical and excited state processes as vapor. It's a big hot mess!

Comment: Only slightly related: [In the recent Con-Ed transformer “fire”, what exactly produced the color of the huge blue glow over New York City?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/414110/102305)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the spectrum due to the high voltage depends on the atomic properties of the metal?

Yes, the atomic emission spectrum is unique for each element. The electrical voltage plays a secondary role in my opinion, it is rather the temperature which determines which line would be visible in the emission spectrum. These days DC arc spectroscopy is not that popular for spectral purposes as better and higher temperature sources such as inductively couple plasma are available. The minimum voltage has to be above break-down voltage of air.